# Swift selector function with optional closure?

Tags: swift, selector, nsnotificationcenter

What am I doing wrong with the `#selector` assignment when I add the notification observer?

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(reloadData), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "reloadCollectionData"), object: nil)

func reloadData(completionHandler: ((Bool) -> Void)? = nil ) {
    mainCollectionView.reloadData()
    
    completionHandler?(true)
}
```

The app crashes whenever I post the notification:

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "reloadCollectionData"), object: nil)
```

I have already tried things like `#selector(reloadData(completionHandler: nil)`

**EDIT:**
I have tried the selector `#selector(reloadData(completionHandler:))` but it still crashes n the line where I post a notification, with the error message:

> `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x8)`

When I change the code as follows everything works fine but it is not really nice to create a function just to call another function

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(testCall), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "reloadCollectionData"), object: nil)
 

func testCall() {
    self.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: It should be `#selector(reloadData(completionHandler:))`

Comment: Update your question (don't post a comment) with the complete and exact error message and clearly point out the exact line causing the issue.

Comment: Also note that the only valid argument to the selector is the `Notification`. You can't pass a selector that take any other parameter.

Comment: @maddy I have updated the question. I also don't want to pass any arguments, therefore I made the parameter `completionHandler` optional.

Answer (score 1):

A completion handler in a notification selector method is nonsensical (and illegal). What do you expect is the object which is supposed to be the receiver of the completion handler ... ?

The syntax of a notification selector is very similar to a target/action selector. The passed parameter must be the type of the affected object (here `Notification`).

```
func reloadData(_ notification : Notification) { ...
```

The alternative is the block based API of `Notification` which is able to capture values of the enclosing function / method.

The only way to pass custom data in a notification object with specified selector is the (optional) `userInfo` dictionary.

Comment: Actually I don't want to pass a `completionHandler` to my function from the selector. But I need to pass a `completionHandler` to the function from other parts of the code. That is why the `completionHandler` is an optional. I could just create an extra function which is my selector method. And this function would do nothing else that calling my `reloadData` without an `completionHandler` (which is possible since the `completionHandler` is an optional). That is pretty much what I did in my question's EDIT.

Comment: The `userInfo` dictionary can take also a closure (completion handler) and it's optional by default